# Integrating an equation with both cos and tan

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

$$\int2\cos^5x\cdot\tan^6x\cdot dx$$
$$2\int\cos^5x\cdot\frac{\sin^6x}{\cos^6x}\cdot dx$$
$$2\int \frac{\sin^6x}{\cos{x}} dx$$
$$2\int\cos^{-2}x\cdot \sin^6x\cdot \cos{x}\cdot dx$$
$$2\int(1-\sin^2x)^{-1}\cdot \sin^6x\cdot \cos{x}\cdot dx$$
$$u = \sin{x}, du = \cos{x}\cdot dx$$
$$2\int(1-u^2)^{-1}\cdot u^6\cdot du$$
$$2\int\frac{u^6}{1-u^2}\cdot du$$

..and now I'm stuck. Maybe I could do something with long division and partial fractions, but this section (I'm doing review) comes before that one. I feel like I'm missing something horribly obvious!

Comment: When you have a rational function of polynomials with the numerator polynomial having the higher degree, you need to make a polynomial division, since the quotient will be just a polynomial.  The "remainder", which is a polynomial of degree lower than that of the denominator _over_ the denominator (divisor) polynomial, then becomes the focus of your integration work (in this case, $ \ \frac{1}{1 - u^2} \ $ ) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have done seems fine... $$\int \dfrac{\sin^6(x)}{\cos(x)}dx = \int \dfrac{\sin^6(x)}{\cos^2(x)}\cos(x)dx = \int \dfrac{\sin^6(x)}{1-\sin^2(x)}\cos(x)dx = \int \dfrac{u^6 du}{1-u^2}$$
We now have
$$\int \dfrac{u^6 du}{1-u^2} = \int \dfrac{du}{1-u^2} - \int \dfrac{1 - u^6}{1-u^2}du = \dfrac12\int \dfrac{du}{1+u} + \dfrac12\int \dfrac{du}{1-u} - \int(1+u^2+u^4)du$$
I trust you can now integrate this.

Comment: So, partial fractions for the first bit, and long division for the second. It's weird, because this question was from the sections before we went over partial fractions. Is there no way to do this without them?